# Promises with node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I know this is a pretty common issue, but I wasn't able to find an explanation for this and I'm trying to use the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#json) examples and go

const fetch = require("node-fetch");

```
fetch(final_url, params)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.ok);
    console.log(res.status);
    console.log(res.statusText);
    console.log(res.headers.raw());
    console.log(res.headers.get("content-type"));
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I've output my `final_url` and `params` variable and they are correct, but I'm not getting anything above except `Promise { pending }`. As I understand it, the second `then` resolves the Promise and passes it to the final `then`, which should output it.

What I've done is put some breakpoints in and used vscode to step through each. I'm still able to see the Promise { pending }, but I'm not sure how I could go about figuring out what was wrong. Maybe there's a way to more effectively use the debugger? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: that code looks right - when are you observing the breakpoints?

Comment: You need to `return res` in the first `.then()` handler

Comment: Specifically, in your case, you should return res.json() in the first .then() as opposed to "return res;", and remove 2nd .then. This way you would avoid creating an unnecessary promise, which has performance implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `return` is missing in `first then`. You need to return to make it available in 2nd then.

Every time when you then, it creates a promise for next to be resolve like a chain. So if you return "something" in then, it will be similar to returning `Promise.resolve("something")`

```
fetch(final_url, params)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.ok);
    console.log(res.headers.get("content-type"));
    return res /// return is missing for next then
  })
```

Sample:

```js
const promise = new Promise((r) => {
  setTimeout(r, 1000, 100);
});
promise
  .then((num) => {
    console.log("1", num);
    return num * 2;
  })
  .then((num) => {
    console.log("2", num);
    return num;
  });

// Output:
1 100
2 200
```