# Node-fetch Promise response property prints as undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I know similar questions have been asked a bunch (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938725/using-a-promise-with-fetch-api-response-still-has-my-data-returning-as-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841642/promises-with-node-fetch)), but I've tried the solutions mentioned there I'm trying to figure out why my node-fetch response isn't behaving as expected. Here's a simple version of the code:

```
 fetch(new URL("https://www.stackoverflow.com")).then(theResponse =>{
      console.log("This prints OK: "); 
      console.log(theResponse.headers);
      console.log("But this prints as undefined:");
      console.log(theResponse.headers["content-encoding"]);
      return theResponse;
})
```

The headers as printed are:

```
{
'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
'cache-control': 'private',
 connection: 'close',
'content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'content-security-policy': "upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com",
etc.
}
```

Why is `theResponse.headers["content-encoding"]` returning as `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`.get` method of the `Headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get):

```
console.log(theResponse.headers.get("Content-Encoding"));
```

Notice that unlike a `Map` or object property access, it works case-insensitively.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the method getAll of Headers object
it return an array

`console.log(theResponse.headers.getAll("Content-Encoding"));`